# Where does /usr/include/mach-o/loader.h come from?

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa, mach-o

It seems that some of my Mac OS X systems have /usr/include/mach-o/loader.h and others don't. I'm confused because this file is documented here:

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/developertools/conceptual/MachORuntime/Reference/reference.html

For example:

```
...Declared in /usr/include/mach-o/loader.h. See also mach_header_64.
```

Does anyone know if this file was removed on any newer versions of Mac OS X? Or if I need to install a special SDK to get it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It exists on my Mac (OS X 10.7), but I do have Xcode installed and it might have come as part of that.

**Edit**

Note that when Xcode compiles anything, it doesn't use the headers in `/usr/include` but the ones in the SDK you have chosen and you can find out where the system headers are by doing a compile and then checking the -isysroot command line switch.  So I have just done a compile and the compiler invocation includes:

```
-isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.7sdk
```

If you open that directory, you'll find it contains a `usr/include/mach-o` subdirectory with the file you want in it.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. On my machine with the issue I do have XCode installed but the ../mach-o/ directory is not present for some reason.

Comment: What version of Xcode? And, if it's one of the versions that doesn't automatically come with Command Line Tools/Unix Development Tools, did you install that package?

Comment: For some cases XCode may be using SDK versions of this file, but XCode definitely is directly reading the /usr/include folder for this file (as per my include statement). When I put the files there, the build started working. Though you are right about this folder existing and containing the desired include files.

Answer (score -1):

loader.h is a hidden file on MAC, so if you don't have hidden files viewable open up a terminal first do this command:

```
defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles TRUE
```

then this command:

```
killall Finder
```

After that follow the path in the finder: /usr/include/mach-o/loader.h

If you do have hidden files all I can say is that I have a OS X 10.7, 10.6 and 10.5 laptop and they have it and have Xcode installed to.